# css justifying alignment of text in a 3 column layout does not work

Tags: html, css, alignment, justify

I am having issue trying to justify the texts for each column so that they get to be more separated and also better-looking. like this one:

[image]

I've searched a lot and done so many suggestions (`vertical align` and `column-gap` were among those suggestions) but they seem not to work in my case. Also, it seems not to be responsive even though I've added the properties I thought was necessary.

How do you get the columns to start from the beginning of the image and get rid of the empty space at the beginning?

```css
 
/*
=============== 
Policy section
===============
*/

 .Policy {
  background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
  background-image: url(https://fit4food2030.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/policy-800x533.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50vh 1em;
  }

  .policy-row {
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  .policy-row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .policy-column{
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 33.3%;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

  .policy p {
    max-width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
  }

.policy h2{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  
  .policy-seperator{
    background-color: #acb930;
    margin: 5px 50px;
    padding: 1px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .policy-column {
      width: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: justify;
    }
    .policy p, .policy h2 {
      font-size: 7rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     max-width: 25%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="Policy">
    <div class="policy-row">
      <div class="policy-column" >
        <h2>overview</h2>
        <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="policy-column" >
        <h2>goals</h2>
        <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="policy-column" >
        <h2>mission</h2>
        <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made I few changes to your code but I think this is the result you wanted.

I advise you to check this to learn better how "display: flex" and all the properties of flexbox work.

Hope this helped :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.Policy {
  background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
  background-image: url(https://fit4food2030.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/policy-800x533.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 1em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.policy-row {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.policy-column p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.policy-seperator {
  background-color: #acb930;
  margin: 5px 0 px;
  padding: 1px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .policy-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .policy p,
  .policy h2 {
    font-size: 7rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="Policy">
  <div class="policy-row">
    <div class="policy-column">
      <h2>overview</h2>
      <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="policy-column">
      <h2>goals</h2>
      <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="policy-column">
      <h2>mission</h2>
      <div class="policy-seperator"></div>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
        here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in your version, only left side of the text is justified but I want them to be justified on both sides. How to achieve that?

Comment: You just add `text-align: justify`